# JS specialchars in string, push and ajax - how to make this work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, quotes, htmlspecialchars

when im using php its easy.
every data received by post or get just put inside:

```
htmlspecialchars($something, ENT_QUOTES);
```

store this in database and thats it.
user can put all of these garbage without interrupt the system:
" ' \ ^ < > /  # $

but when im working with angular or js more precisely,
things are a little bit different.

1. sending $http, just doesnt work,
   i know i can use encodeuri functions but then i need to decode each parameter i pass, i mean,
   i cant send a full array encoded and decode it fully in php.
   for example i want let the user put this input and encode all of this json and decode it easily without making the code to load too much time:

> ```
> var my_json = [
>     {
>       name: "some#thing",
>       phone: "some$</script>thing1",
>     },
>     {
>       name: "someth"ing",
>       phone: "someth'ing1",
>     },
>   ];
> ```

ratther i do now is using mysqli_real_escape_string.
2. trying to catch some data with $scope (angular) or jquery selector.
then push this to an array. everything works until you put those troublemakers: " ' \ ^ < > /  # $

so what to do?
ive tried everything.

im trying to do this for example:

```
var newStation = $scope.list.stations.split("|||");
    var newObject = {
      name: newStation[0],
      address: newStation[1],
      phone: newStation[2],
    };
    $scope.stations.push(newObject);
```

and then receive an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined

ive tried using escapeHTML function which i found in stackoverflow when sending $http, but this not works too..

thanks.

Comment: "its easy" --- and you're doing it wrong already. You must **NOT** `htmlspecialchars` before you put it in the database.

Comment: so how to insert into the database in order to prevent sql injection?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` has nothing to do with sql injections at all. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/251311